# Update document issue

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a log stash running pulling records from postgresql and creating documents in elastic search, but whenever i am trying to update a record in postgres the same is not getting reflected in elastic search, here is my INPUT & OUTPUT configs let me know if i am missing anything here,

```
  input {
    jdbc {
    # Postgres jdbc connection string to our database, mydb
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5009/data"
    # The user we wish to execute our statement as
    jdbc_user => "data"
    jdbc_password=>"data"
    # The path to our downloaded jdbc driver
    jdbc_driver_library => "/postgresql-9.4.1209.jar"
    # The name of the driver class for Postgresql
    jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
    #sql_log_level => "debug"
    jdbc_paging_enabled => "true"
    jdbc_page_size => "5000"
    schedule => "* * * * *"
    # our query
    clean_run => true
    last_run_metadata_path => "/logstash/.test_metadata"
    #use_column_value => true
    #tracking_column => id
    statement => "SELECT id,name,update_date from data where update_date > :sql_last_value"
    }
    }

    output {
    elasticsearch{
    hosts => ["127.0.0.1"]
    index => "test_data"
    action => "index"
    document_type => "data"
    document_id => "%{id}"
    upsert => ' {
    "name" : "%{data.name}",
    "update_date" : "%{data.update_date}"
    } '
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to track a date/timestamp column instead of the id column. If you have an `UPDATE_DATE` column that changes on each update, that would be good.

Your SELECT statement will only grab new records (i.e. `id > last_id`) and if you update a record, its id won't change, hence that updated record won't be picked up by the `jdbc` input the next time it runs.

Comment: tracking_column => update_date
    statement => "SELECT id,name,update_date from data where id > :sql_last_value"

Comment: You neither need `tracking_column` nor `use_column_value` as by default `:sql_last_value` will contain a timestamp

Comment: statement => "SELECT id,name,update_date from actmon.test where update_date > :sql_last_value"

Comment: sorry didn't help

Comment: Have you erased `/logstash/.test_metadata` since it probably contained info about the id column?